# Multiplying binomial by negative 1 to reverse order of variables

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I apologize for asking about an incredibly simple math concept but I'm trying to brush up on my algebra and Googling hasn't helped, I don't know the name of the rule I am looking for.

According to [a problem I've been walking through](https://i.stack.imgur.com/riThy.png) step-by-step on Wolfram Alpha if I have a fraction like this:

$$ \frac{a – x}{ax(x - a)}
    $$

I can factor out a -1 from the demoninator and it becomes:

$$ \frac{a – x}{ax*-1*(a - x)}
    $$

The order of a and x was somehow reversed, apparently this is just a rule in algebra. Can somebody tell me the name of the rule so I can learn more about it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isnt a rule, its a property of the inverse of a element:
$$(a-b)=-(b-a) = -1*b-1*(-a)=a-b$$
this can be seen simply by opening the parenthesis and multyplying each member by $-1$ or in other words changing the signs

Comment: Oh jeez, yeah that seems pretty obvious now. Thanks for taking the time to answer anyway, I appreciate it.